# Is there any pure digital phase shifter circuit?

Tags: digital-logic, phase-shift

It is possible to make analog phase shifter circuits:

[image: analog phase shifter]

But In digital electronics (logic circuits), is it possible to shift the phase of an input digital wave?

The frequency of the input wave is 1MHz at most.

Comment: That would be a delay.

Comment: @Icy What circuit can produce that "delay"?

Comment: A shift register with a clock can be used as pure digital delay

Comment: @Icy The clock will change the input wave shape.

Comment: Yes. if you need long delays with minimum error you need large shift registers and high clock rates. You could use your analogue delay line, with a pulse shaper (Schmidt trigger) on the output, but again it will change your pulse shape.

Comment: A long chain of inverters will apply a systematic delay without changing the pulse width, although it may sharpen the pulses and you have to make sure the delay is balanced.

Comment: @pjc50 Inverters don't have delay in theory.

Comment: Inverters only have zero delay in the perfect world of simulation. It is not possible to build a practical circuit that has no delay. Although the perpetual motion/zero net energy nuts would try to convince you otherwise.

Comment: @BlueSky, is it a requirement to maintain the shape of the input waveform? If so, it is not really a digital delay. It is an analog delay. Can you explain what this output will be used for?

Comment: @mkeith. the same wave at the input must be at the output, but with a delay.

Comment: A 1MHz signal would need to be sampled at 2MHz according to Nyquist's theorem. Then you can delay it however much you want and then ouput the same signal with a time delay.

Comment: How much delay? Is it fixed or variable? Maybe you can use an actual delay line.

Answer (score 3):

Yes of course it's possible - any analogue filter can be taken into the Z domain and a digital equivalent constructed. This happens all the time. So if you have an analogue circuit that does what your need there are several methodologies that produce an equivalent digital "circuit" that can be implemented in MCUs, FPGAs etc..

Try looking up: -

- Impulse invariance method
- Bilinear transformation

As to whether your original analogue circuit is a pure delay, that is another matter. Anyway, I forgot that I wrote a [**paper**](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjQ1c-M8uDJAhUBdx4KHS-dCX4QFggdMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.jamesoakwood.co.uk%2FDigital%2520filter%2520design%2520for%2520Analogue%2520engineers.pdf&usg=AFQjCNEnXlnSOSQWu9-O2N_8hz1w7g0CoQ&sig2=m_uUNgU0idBAldsRYM-jKQ) on it and the front sheet should help you understand: -

[image]

It begins with a simple RC and converts it to an op-amp equivalent in position (2). Position (3) re-shapes it slightly and position (4) arrives at the finished digital filter.

Comment: What is "Z domain"? impedance you mean?

Comment: @BlueSky https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Z-transform
It's the discrete transform rather than the continuous transform into the frequency domain.

Comment: sorry but your answer is to complicated to me. what is that XOR sign in the wiring of the circuit for example?

Comment: It's a signal adder.

Answer (score 2):

A shift register with a clock can be used as pure digital delay, but that will result in the output pulse being modified, such that the output pulse will be synchronised with the clock.

To minimise the synchronisation errors, you would use a high clock rate, but that has the disadvantage of requiring a larger shift register.

An alternative would be to use an analogue delay line (such as posted in your question), with a pulse shaper (Schmidt trigger) on the output, but again this will have some effect on your pulse shape.

Comment: Can you give a little explaination as to how this works for an "input digital wave" as mentioned in the question. By this I presume the OP means like the digital equivalence of an analogue signal.

Comment: @Andyaka. It's a square wave with varied width (but not shorter than 1ns).

Answer (score 2):

There are components available to delay digital signals by specified amounts. Many of these components, called delay lines, offer tapped delays in steps.

In days gone by there were lumped constant delay lines that offered from 1 to 10 delay taps with each delay element being an L/C component pair.

Since the L/C type delay lines did have the effect of changing the rise and fall time of the signal some various manufacturers then introduced buffered lumped constant delay lines. These would have an internal high speed inverter chip such as an SN74S04 that would buffer the input and five outputs. These were specified so that the delay of the inverters was included in the tap to tap delay.

These days various manufacturers have produced components called "silicon delay lines" that offer various features. You can find tapped delay lines and programmable delay lines. Some manufacturers to consider are Linear Technology and Maxim.